# Função dentro de função - PHP

Tags: php

Quero fazer uma função que gere uma string no formato alfanumero ( XXXXXX-XXXXXX ) e fiz a seguinte função para tal:

```
    private static function generateCode() {
    function generate() {
        $alphaNumeric = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'; // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
        $code = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
            $code .= $alphaNumeric[ rand(0,strlen($alphaNumeric) - 1) ];
        }
        return $code; // ex: X0XX0X
    }

    return sprintf("%s-%s",generate(),generate());

}
```

Porem nao consigo usar a generate(), como faço para ter essa função dentro da outra?

Comment: Me parece que funciona direitinho: https://ideone.com/7MRHUm

Answer (score 2):

Era para estar funcionando, se você disser o erro que ocorre talvez consiga aponta aonde foi, de qualquer forma não sei realmente porque fez isso, você poderia simplesmente criar outro método privado e já resolveria e para chamar usaria `self::generate()`

```
private static function generateCode()
{
    return sprintf("%s-%s", self::generate(), self::generate());
}

private static function generate()
{
    $alphaNumeric = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'; // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789

    $code = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $code .= $alphaNumeric[ rand(0,strlen($alphaNumeric) - 1) ];
    }

    return $code; // ex: X0XX0X
}
```